# Making R as a server

Tags: r

Well, i'm trying to make a server to connect into a APN. The whole operation works like this:

[image]

The sim card send the information to APN and the APN send the information for a server by their server ip,

my question is: is possible do create a server with R for this? I mean to receive the information from the APN? I'm studying the [servr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/servr/index.html) but the [read me](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/servr/readme/README.html) unfortunately
requires a lot of previous information. Is that possible?

Comment: What file format/protocol will the APN be sending the data to R?

Comment: I dont know the file format, the information that i need is just a string

Comment: RStudio has a free **Rstudio Server** that you can download and use and read in string data, you can trigger job tasks with the package `cronr` to read in the data every second.